# Does $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_k^2<\infty$ imply $\sup_{n\in \mathbb{N}}na_n<\infty$?

Tags: analysis

Let $a_k>0, k\in \mathbb{N}$. Suppose that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n^2<\infty$. Does it implies $\sup_{n\in \mathbb{N}}na_n<\infty$? Thanks.

Comment: Pad any square summable sequence with enough zeroes and it satisfies the first but fails the second.

Comment: If $a_n\searrow 0$ then you can conclude that $n^{1/2}a_n\to 0$, though.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff How to deduce it?

Comment: Your question was put on hold, the message above (should give an explanation why. (In particular, [this link](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9960) might be useful.) You might try to edit your question to address these issues. Note that the next edit puts your post in the review queue, where users can vote to reopen this. (Therefore it would be good to avoid minor edits and improve your question as much as possible with the next edit.)

Answer (score 5):

No, for example, $a_n = n^{-3/4}$.